# How do I Write a RegEx that will Edit Only Very Specific Data

Tags: regex

I'm trying to write a regular expression that will find data scattered throughout several files that look something like this:

```
[Something here](HTTP://somesite.com)
[DifferentStuff](HTTPS://Another.org)
[yetagain](HTTP://elsewhere)
```

What I want is to retain just the data that is within the two square brackets, like this

```
Something here
DifferentStuff
yetagain
```

The situation is that it is critical to include the HTTP:// or HTTPS:// because there are other similar entries in the documents that do not point to an external site which I do not want changed. In addition, the data I wish to edit may come at the end of a sentence ending in punctuation, the beginning of a sentence starting with a capital letter, or in the middle of a sentence which could result in a double space character.

I'm not sure, but I think retaining the data in brackets will automatically keep the beginning character capitalized should that be the case, and if, at the end of the sentence, the punctuation should also not be a problem. It's just the regular expression itself that I can't seem to get right and the possibility of ending up with a bunch of double-space characters.

Here are a few of the expressions I have tried that don't work. Note that while I really do need to make sure that I am only editing those that contain HTTP(S):// I left this out of many of my attempts just to get further along:

([[^]]+]()((http|https)://[^)]+))

([([^]]+)](([^)]+)))

[([^[]]+)](([^)]+))

[[^[]]*](.+)

[([^[]]+)](.+)

([([^[]]+)](.+))

[([^[]]+)](.+)

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: "there are other similar entries in the documents that do not point to an external site which I do not want changed." - please include examples of these too, that is essential to be able to create a tested / verified regex. You might wish to peek on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean/22944075#22944075

Comment: RegexMagic has a free trail https://www.regexmagic.com/ or just use regex101 if you prefer. This is a great opportunity to actually learn regex (teach a man to fish and all that)

Comment: From regex tag info: “Because regular expressions are not fully standardized, all questions with this tag should also include a tag specifying the applicable programming language or tool.”

Comment: Depending  on regex flavour, this should work: `\[(.+?)(?=\]\(https?://)`, result in group 1 `$1`

Comment: The files I wish to edit are notes in Obsidian. A great many of the notes have peoples names with pointers to Wikipedia. This just takes up space and colors the names which I don't want, looks messy and causes me a lot of future editing when I want to add the note to an external document. As for the data I do not want to get edited, the format is the same [somestuff](somestuff), it just does not contain HTTP:// or HTTPS://

Comment: The clarification needed is **What language/tool are you using**?

Comment: Ken, the good practice in this site is when you get answer of your question and it work for you to accept is. This way the software behind will propose this answer in future searches.

Answer (score 0):

Using `awk` and sample `HTTP` and `HTTPS` search you can do it. The command is:

```
awk -F'[(:]' '$2=="HTTP" || $2=="HTTPS" {gsub("\\[",""); gsub("\\]","");print $1}' <input file>
```

`-F` set delimiters, then search if second token is `HTTP` or `HTTPS`, strip square brackets and then print first tokes

With pure regex you can try something like:

```
\[(.+?)\]\((HTTPS|HTTP):\/\/.*
```

or

```
\[(.+?)\]\(HTTPS?:\/\/.*
```

You can check explanation and execution [here](https://regex101.com/r/nOzNOB/1).

Comment: Sorry, I don't know awk... Don't even know what it is... The files I wish to edit are notes in Obsidian... But thanx.

Comment: @Ken, this is important information and you should include it in the question. Will edit my answer and will try to give you some solution

Answer (score 0):

I apologize and I will attempt to be more explicit in the future. Meanwhile, I have, through trial and error, independently found the answer. The following works quite well.

Find: `\[([^\[\]]+)\]\((https?://)[^)]+\)`

Replace: `$1`

Thanx for all the help... It got me thinking!